# I need Content instead of URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
add_action("admin_init", "social_share_settings");
function add_social_share_icons($content)
{
    $html = "Share on: ";

    global $post;

    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $url = esc_url($url);

    if(get_option("social-share-facebook") == 1)
    {
        $html = $html . "Whatsapp";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function as `get_content` in wordpress. What you need is `get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser)`. This will return content of the current post.

**Optional Parameters for get_the_content**

$more_link_text
*(string) (optional) Content for when there is more text.
Default: null*

$stripteaser
*(boolean) (optional) Strip teaser content before the more text.
Default: false*

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

**Get Specific Post Content**

If you want to get the content of a specific post you can use `get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);`.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field

**UPDATE:**

In response to your new question. You are outputting the content in to a href link, so your browser will be encoding the spaces to %20. This is because you can't have literal spaces in URLs.

**UPDATE 2**

I have just noticed you are creating a share button to whatsapp.  Below is another way to structure of a whatsapp share link. Using that method your string would not be urlencoded, because it is in a data-attribute. I think your method would work as well, because whatsapp should decode the %20 at it's end. Note: A string in a URL must be urlencoded, so you can't remove the &20 while it is a URL.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website:" data-href="">Share</a>
```

Comment: You should really add an additional update to your question rather than editing the entire question, because now my answer is redundant.

Comment: Oh.. Will make edits again.. I was confused really about what to do and edited.. This is my first question  in the community.

Comment: No problem. People usually add an UPDATE title under there initial question, like I have done in my answer.

Comment: You would need to provide an example of where/how you are trying to output the `?text` query string. In PHP you can use `urldecode()` when you are outputting the query string.

Comment: I am making sharing icon where I need content of the post instead of link. Tried adding urldecode($con) instead of $con in the url.... but no luck